# Searching for larger versions of a smaller image on Google Image Search

Tags: google-image-search

Search on [Google Images](https://images.google.com) doesn't seem to work anymore [see [this screen clip](https://i.imgur.com/1iknyxD.mp4)]. Any solutions?

*My Objective:* To search larger versions of a smaller image.

**[Google Support Thread](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/140716491)**

Comment: Works fine for me, something on your end is blocking Google. Remove adblockers, check your connection, etc. That's not on Google side.

Comment: Hello @Zygd, please see the screen clip, it is just a one min video.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 okay.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications SE.